# If I have multiple dotnetcore websites hosted in IIS on a windows machine, do they all share the same dotnetcore process?

Tags: .net-core, iis

Suppose you have multiple websites hosted in IIS that use dotnetcore 2.0 and the aspnetcore runtime module for it. Suppose they're all on the same windows 2019 server.

If some of them have their ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT set to Development via web.config and some set to Staging (or any other custom environment created by the person who wrote it), is it possible for one or more of these websites to run in a mode that isn't what their configs are set to? Do these websites all share the same running instance of dotnetcore?

Have a peculiar issue right now where there are multiple iis sites cohosted on a machine (wasn't my decision) and a couple of them look like they're using the connectionstrings defined in the appsettings.development file instead of whatever they're set to because OTHER sites on the same windows machine are set to Development. There are no hardcoded environment variables at the OS level as an ENV: or in IIS itself outside of what's in the web.config that would set this. I'm 99% sure it's a code problem, but wanted to ask SO for their sage opinion.

Any insight is helpful. Thanks.

Comment: It is ASP.NET Core on IIS, so that you can learn and write the simplest hello world sample and let it print out the current process ID. Then by deploying this sample application on IIS multiple times (as different sites for example), you can easily tell what's the answer for your questions.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, they should not be using the same dotnetcore process. There are application pools and they can be created for each website separately. Each application pool will have its own process.

Now, for using the appsettings.json.

When the process starts, it throws enviorment variables and then the .net (in the code) does the magic for you for loading the specific one. So, in order to use different appsettings.json files (apssetings.development.json or appsettings.staging.json) you need to pass Envioroment Variable:

`ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` like `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development` or `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Staging`